# SQL Server: get max value between a range of values with additional data

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, aggregate

Most people want the max value but I need the max value within a range PLUS additional data. For example I have a list of teams and their managers and their managers id. I looked in google / stackoverflow but most people want the max value only but I need additional columns too which is why I am asking this question.

**Table1**:

```
team  mgr_level mgr_id
-----------------------
aa     1          111
aa     2          222 
aa     3          333
bb     1          111
bb     2          222
cc     1          111
cc     2          222
cc     3          444 
cc     4          888
```

**Table2**:

```
employee       emp_id   team
------------------------------
smith, mary      23     aa
jones, john      34     bb 
ramjet, roger    98     cc
james, adam      111    mgr_team
green, rachel    222    mgr_team
bruin, breezly   333    mgr_team
runner, road     444    mgr_team
potter, harry    888    mgr_team
```

I need to select the maximum(mgr_id) that is between 222 and 444 with other data (team and mgr_id).

Result needed as shown below. Is there a way to do it in one step rather than in two steps?

```
name           team   primary_mgr_id  manager_name
-----------------------------------------------
smith, mary     aa      333           bruin, breezly
jones, john     bb      222           green, rachel  
ramjet, roger   cc      444           runner, road
```

I tried this and SQL Server keeps returning multiple rows for each name: what am I doing wrong?

```
select max(mgr_id) as [primary_mgr_id], t2.employee, t1.mgr_id
from table2 t2
inner join table1 t1 on t2.team = t2.team
group by t2.employee, t1.mgr_id
```

Thank you for your help.
Sven

Comment: i added it!  thanks i forgot to add it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **One Option is with the help of a Row_Number()**

```
Select Name = A.Employee
      ,A.Team
      ,primary_mgr_id = B.Mgr_ID
      ,manager_name   = B.manager_name
From  Table2 A
Join (
        Select A.*
              ,manager_name = employee
              ,RN = Row_Number() over (Partition By A.Team Order by A.mgr_level desc)
         From Table1 A
         Join Table2 B on (A.Mgr_ID=B.Emp_ID)
         Where mgr_id between 222 and 444
     ) B on A.Team=B.Team and B.RN=1
```

Returns

```
Name            Team    primary_mgr_id  manager_name
smith, mary     aa      333             bruin, breezly
jones, john     bb      222             green, rachel
ramjet, roger   cc      444             runner, road
```

> **Another Option is to use a CROSS APPLY**

```
Select Name = A.Employee
      ,A.Team
      ,primary_mgr_id = B.Mgr_ID
      ,manager_name   = B.employee
From  Table2 A
Cross Apply (
        Select Top 1 C.*,D.employee 
         From  Table1 C
         Join  Table2 D on (emp_id = mgr_id)
         where C.Team=A.Team and mgr_id between 222 and 444 Order by mgr_level desc
      ) B
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this the one you're after?

```
SELECT
    employee AS name, team, max_mgr_id AS primary_mgr_id, t3.employee as manager_name
FROM
    table2 t2
JOIN (
    SELECT team, MAX(mgr_id) AS max_mgr_id
    FROM table1
) t1 ON t2.team = t1.team
JOIN table2 t3 ON t3.emp_id = t1.max_mgr_id AND t3.team = 'mgr_team'
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do this as using `outer apply`

```
select t2.*, t1.mgr_id as primary_mgr_id , t1.name as manager_name
from table2 t2 outer apply
     (select t1.mgr_id, tt2.name
      from table1 t1 join
           table2 tt2
           on t1.mgr_id = tt2.emp_id
      where t1.team = t2.team and
            t1.mgr_id between 222 and 444
      order by t1.mgr_id desc
     ) t1;
```